# Create bookmark folders on iPhone or iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, mobileme, bookmarks

Is it possible to create a new bookmark folder using iOS? I share my bookmarks between four devices (using MobileMe) and it would be useful to be able to structure them in a useful way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you do it in iOS 4.1:

1. In Safari, hit the bookmarks icon
2. Press the "Edit" button in the lower left
3. In the lower right, a "New Folder" button appears. Press it.
4. Type in the name of the folder and hit "Done" on the keyboard.

[image]